# Is it possible to make an iframe a background in html5?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to set a YouTube video as the background on a project I'm working on and all the research I've been doing has been less that helpful.

I haven't found anything that even has mention of this being possible or not anywhere, so I don't know if this even is possible. It may be that the answer is "that's not possible".

Comment: yes just place it in background with a negative `z-index`. however a video would be a wrong sue for an iframe. easier to sue the video or emdia tag directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just push the iframe in the background with: `position: fixed` and a negative `z-index` - However for redundancy you should upload the video to your webspace and include it directly as video or media tag.

```css
iframe {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* for demo purpose only */
* {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rLtwToALM60" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<p>Random content</p>
<p>Random content</p>
<p>Random content</p>
<p>Random content</p>
<p>Random content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. I put a quick codepen for you. https://codepen.io/CrystalRcodes/pen/ExbRVXw
see if this helps you. Let me know.

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  outline: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: hsl(172deg 18% 27% / 0%);
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>The Video Background </h1>
    This is a sample text or div
  </div>

  <iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vYPYgHwf2KA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: this does nto amke the video as background of the website. Also position every text relatively will eb a pain in the butt for more content that just be responsive. Last but not least, height and width attributes onyl allow numebrs as value. It is always set in pixel. you can't set a value liek % or px to it.

Comment: this is just an idea. sorry its not the one you are looking for